# How to tell when a response is completed and I can close a socket

Tags: java, scala, sockets

I have a function that connects to a service running on a port using sockets, issues a command and reads the response. My code never seems to terminate though, as the `reader.readLine` just blocks, waiting for the server to send more data.

How can I get the code to terminate? Do I need to check the response and if there is what I determine to be a completed response then close the connection?

```
  def getDef(word: String) = {
    import java.net._
    import java.io._

    val s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9000)
    val in = s.getInputStream
    val out = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream)
    val bufIns = new BufferedInputStream(in)
    val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bufIns, "utf8"));
    out.println("define "  + word)
    out.flush()
    var response = ""
    var curr = reader.readLine
    while(curr != null) {
      response += curr
      println("Received: " + curr)
      curr = reader.readLine
    }
    println("now close down and return") //Never reaches this point
    s.close()
    response
  }
```

Comment: You already have your answer: _"... check the response and if there is what I determine to be a completed response then close the connection"_. This is a fundamental network protocol design issue.

Comment: readLine hangs if you do not receive EOF. So it is better to read raw data - and the covert it to text. But the best solution is to use [apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html)

Comment: It doesn't appear to be http. So HttpClient isn't going to help

Comment: As Jim mentioned, this is really up to you.  There are two general classes of protocols (this all applies to any arbitrary length collection by the way), those where they tell you the length of the message in some sort of header, and those that end the message with some sort of delimiter.  Either way, you, the client, need to be prepared to read exactly what is required and then ship that message up to your callers.  Whether you then close the connection, if it's a one-off, or keep it open to process more messages, is another decision that only can be answered by knowing the protocol.